# Using Maven properties to connect to a database

Tags: java, maven

I have a Maven project that runs some tests against a database. I can run these tests using `mvn clean verify` but I want to specify some database properties eg. database name, port name etc... in my pom.xml file that I can use within Java to create a database connection.

I have added this to my POM,

```
  <properties>
    <server>localhost</server>
    <database>mydatabase</database>
    <port>1433</port>
  </properties>
```

Can I access these properties from my Java code, or will I need to create a Maven plugin and pass these properties as parameters to my plugin and call `clean verify` from my custom plugin?

Comment: what dose "use within java" mean? how is your "java codes" started? it starts from maven by some plugin or just as normal java application?

Comment: The project is a `cucumber-jvm` project and is just for testing so at the moment it is started by running `mvn test`. Properties are read from a file, the database connection is set up and then the tests are run. I think What I want is the database properties to be specified via command line so I can specify the database like `mvn test -Dserver=localhost, database=..` etc.. I am trying to get these tests to run on Jenkins CI server downstream of a project that builds a database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enable Resource Filtering (e.g., for test resources):

```
<build>
  <testResources>
    <testResource>
      <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
    </testResource>
  </testResources>
</build>
```

Create a db.properties under `src/test/resources`:

```
server=${server}
port=${port}
```

In your test, read `db.properties`:

```
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/db.properties")
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(inputStream);
```

[Maven: The Complete Reference](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-description.html) has an overview on how it works:

Comment: If anyone finds this, the maven reference link is broken, [use this one instead](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/).

Comment: Use the POM documentation [here](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Resources) instead

Answer (score 0):

When you run your tests you can pass Maven properties into the java application with Surefire plugin equivalent of -D on the command line that runs the tests.\

This shows how to do that:

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html

Comment: Can I then just access these using `System.getProperty()`?

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot from your project use those properties (maven properties) by `System.getProperty()`.

because maven works at building time, and your codes work at runtime. But you could let maven set some properties (properties file for example) during building, then your class could get those values.

Usually system properties were set when jvm starts. If the VM, on which your project is running, is started from maven, by some plugin for example `mvn jetty:run` then you have chance to get the properties defined in maven. However if your project is running on a VM, which has nothing to do with maven, you cannot get those properties.